# How to write two-step first-l2e-then-l2o IQueryable?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

Let's say I have an Entity Framwork query

```
var query = db.Entities
  .FancyQueryStuff()
  .Where(GetFilter()) // *
  .OrderBy(GetSort()) // *
  .Take(GetNumberOfRows()) // *
;
```

and figure that this query is very slow. Testing reveals that the following rewrite is much faster:

```
var ids = db.Entities
  .FancyQueryStuff()
  .Where(GetFilter()) // *
  .OrderBy(GetSort()) // *
  .Take(GetNumberOfRows()) // *
  .Select(x => x.Id)
  .ToArray()
;

var query = db.Entries
  .FancyQueryStuff()
  .OrderBy(GetSort()) // *
  .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Whether that is quicker depends on a lot of things, including the sql database used, but I have a scenario in which this is the case with SQL Server and a particular query doing heavy joining.

Now the problem I have is that I want to use libraries that take `IQueryable`s and apply `Where`, `OrderBy`, `Take` and `Skip` internally according to UI information the get from somewhere else (DevExpress/Telerik grids with paging, where the user clicks on captions to sort, etc.).

That means I have to write the query in a form where all the rows marked with an asterisk can be applied by a third-party framework.

With Devextreme, for example, you have a method that takes the query plus a data structure representing the filter/sorting/paging in a custom format and returns the query results you are supposed to pass to a client in an html application:

```
var result = DataSourceLoader.Load(query, loadOptions);
```

`DataSourceLoader.Load` applies everything of the kind I marked with an asterisk to the end of the query, executes it and returns the result.

I guess it's possible to do what I want with some heavy guns of linq magic (dynamic linq?), but before I try myself I thought maybe someone already has a snippet ready for this probably not too uncommon use case.

Comment: How do you relate your IQuerable with Grid?

Comment: @AdilMammadov Added more information about that.

Comment: As I undertsand you provide query like *IQueryable<Person> query = context.Persons;* and loadOptions is generated automatically by third-party framework am I right? Do you have access to *GetFilter(), GetSort()* methods in your code or they are applied automatically?

Comment: The are applied automatically and internally, I have no control over how DevExtreme (or the other frameworks) do it - that's the problem. I need to present it with *one* IQueryable that then, on being applied those things to, evaluates the way I wrote in the second sample.

Comment: I have no exprience with such third party frameworks, may be I am wrong, but I think it should be possible to get filter or sorting options from loadOptions. Please have a look at: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T169937

Comment: It's not only such third-party tools that work that way. WCF Data Services and WCF Ria Services also operate under the condition that you provide them with a base IQueryable and they do the filtering, sorting and paging on it.